# varnish - why two processes

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

For Varnish, I see two processes running, one is child of other as

```
nobody   10499 23634  0 22:25 ?        00:00:00 varnishd -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -s malloc,1G -T 127.0.0.1:2000 -a 0.0.0.0:80
root     23634     1  0 19:33 ?        00:00:00 varnishd -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -s malloc,1G -T 127.0.0.1:2000 -a 0.0.0.0:80
```

How does it actually work?

Comment: Are you asking how Varnish works? (Did you look at the documentation: https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/ ?) Or are you asking how creating a child process with fork() works? (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)

Comment: I read the docs. now I know the answer. Posting the text here. It could help others

Answer (score 7):

Varnish has two main processes: the management process and the child process. The management
process apply configuration changes (VCL and parameters), compile VCL, monitor Varnish, initialize
Varnish and provides a command line interface, accessible either directly on the terminal or through a
management interface.

The management process polls the child process every few seconds to see if it's still there. If it doesn't get
a reply within a reasonable time, the management process will kill the child and start it back up again. The
same happens if the child unexpectedly exits, for example from a segmentation fault or assert error.

This ensures that even if Varnish does contain a critical bug, it will start back up again fast. Usually within
a few seconds, depending on the conditions.